# postgresql: правильно построить индексы для ускорения выполнения запроса с group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, оптимизация, index, оптимизация-запросов

в таблице `data_t` есть поле `words`, содержащее фразы, разделённые запятой:

```
word1, word2, word3 and word4, other words
```

требуется получить по таблице статистику какие фразы сколько раз встречаются в записях

написал такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS count, word AS value
FROM (
    SELECT 
        trim(regexp_split_to_table(words, ',')) AS word
    FROM 
        data_t
) AS t
GROUP BY word
```

всё хорошо, но не устраивает скорость работы запроса, когда выбирается из таблицы много записей

подскажите, можно ли его ускорить?

поле `words` не индексировано и думаю, что построив правильные индексы можно решить проблемы, вопрос лишь в том, какие индексы нужны?

или индексирование не поможет?
если смотреть в сторону предобработки (например создать специальный столбец `prepared_words`), то какие данные в нем должны храниться? массив предварительно выделенных слов (что даст экономию времени на использовании `trim` и `regexp_split_to_table`?

Comment: а что скажет начальник explain?   если у вас выборка по всей таблице, то пользы от индекса нет, можно попробовать create view либо пересоздать таблицу. regex действительно медленная вещь.

Comment: не во всей таблице (на всей я проверял просто), выборка с `where`, но на всей просто заметил насколько низкопроизводительное решение :(

Comment: функциональный индекс тогда. если размеры позволяют дублировать таблицу, дублируйте с нужными значениями.

Comment: Нельзя ли прикрутить Full Text Search?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, полнотекстовый поиск (GIN индексы) не помогали :(

Answer (score 2):

Поле words содержит фразы, разделенные запятыми, создание обычного индекса на этом поле не даст значительного улучшения производительности.

Могу предложить следующие варианты ускорения скрипта:

а. Создать индекс на выражение.

```
CREATE INDEX words_expr_idx ON data_t (trim(regexp_split_to_table(words, ',')));
```

б. Создать функциональный индекс.

```
CREATE INDEX words_func_idx ON data_t ((regexp_split_to_table(words, ',')));
```

в. Дообработать поле words в prepared_words для получения статистики. Например, так:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count, word AS value
FROM (
    SELECT 
        regexp_substr(prepared_words, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) AS word
    FROM 
        data_t
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(prepared_words, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
) t
GROUP BY word;
```

г. Кэшировать результаты запроса, но это не для всех целей может помочь.

Comment: попытка построить индекс на выражение даёт ошибку `ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in index expressions
LINE 1: ...E INDEX words_expr_idx ON data_t (trim(regexp_spl...`

Comment: попытка построить функциональный индекс даёт ошибку `ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in index expressions
LINE 1: ...REATE INDEX words_func_idx ON data_t ((regexp_spl...`